# Debugging a segmentation fault when I do ctrl c

Tags: debugging, gdb, copy-paste

I get a segmentation fault when I cancel my program. I am using gdb for debugging, the problem is that when I press Ctrl-C while I am debugging gdb does not cancel the program and do what it is supposed to do that is stop it.

What I want is do the Ctrl-C and do not allow gdb to stop it. Is there any way to do this? Any other recommendations for debugging? I cannot use printf because sincerely I have not a clear idea where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

gdb is intercepting the signal.  When you press CTRL-C, you're actually causing the terminal driver to generate a SIGINT.

What you need to do is have GDB generate the SIGINT using the **signal** command.  the syntax is

> > signal *num*

and man signal will tell you the signal number (in this case, SIGINT is signal 2, so `signal 2` will do it.)

#### Update

Sure enough, you can use the symbolic name.  `info signal` will tell you all the names etc.

Oh, by the way, odds are that you have a signal handler installed for SIGINT and the arguments aren't right somehow.

Comment: You can also use symbolic names for the signals, like "signal SIGINT".

Comment: it was a little non obvious to me - we need to drop into gdb prompt (say by ctrl+c itself) followed by `signal SIGINT` would resume and send signal to program.

Answer (score 27):

An alternative is to stop gdb from catching the SIGINT by typing `handle SIGINT noprint pass` at the gdb prompt before running the program.

Comment: Well, yeah, but sometimes being able to interrupt gdb is handy.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer being preferable by impacting program timing and therefore behaviour the least, plus it actually answers the op's question.

Answer (score 7):

One option is to load the core file produced when not running in the debugger into gdb.  From within gdb, type `core-file [filename]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also send the CTRL-C (aka SIGINT) from another terminal: kill -INT