# Signal handling in debug and in free execution

Tags: c++, unix, signals, boost-asio

I have to handle `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` in my program that uses Boost.Asio. I use `boost::asio::signal_set::async_wait()` for this.

The problem is that the signal handler gets the control only when I simply run the app but does not when I debug it.

Here is some code:

```cpp
Proxy::Proxy():
    signals_(ioContext_, SIGINT, SIGTERM)
{
    signals_.async_wait(
        [this](const boost::system::error_code& error, int)
        {
            if (!error)
                ioContext_.stop();
        }
    );
}

Proxy::run()
{
    ioContext_.run();
}
```

When we `run()` the `Proxy`, `ioContext_` starts processing events. If we just simply run the program and do `Ctrl+C` in terminal, the signal handler (that is lambda) stops `ioContext_` (as we expect) and `io_context::run` gives the control back. But in debug mode the program reacts to `Ctrl+C` but the execution stops somewhere in `epoll_wait()`. If we continue the execution, it hangs on somewhere in `epoll_wait()` and so on.

Here is a stack trace of where the execution stops:

```
epoll_wait
boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::run
boost::asio::detail::scheduler::do_one_run
boost::asio::detail::scheduler::run
boost::asio::io_context::run
Proxy::run
main
```

Why does it happen in debug mode but does not otherwise?

Comment: Are you using GDB as your debugger?

Comment: Travis Gockel, yes, I am

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is GDB uses `SIGINT` as the mechanism to interrupt the program and allow you to start your debugging.

```
(gdb) info signals SIGINT
Signal        Stop      Print   Pass to program Description
SIGINT        Yes       Yes     No              Interrupt
```

This is saying that GDB should not pass `SIGINT`s to the program, but should use that to stop the program and drop you into the GDB prompt. The easiest mechanism to send it onward to your program is to send the signal from GDB at this point:

```
(gdb) signal SIGINT
```

Now your program should continue on its way as expected.

---

Depending on how often you do this, typing `signal SIGINT` might get inconvenient. Luckily, GDB lets you modify the way it handles [signals](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Signals.html). You want `SIGINT` to not stop the program (drop you into the GDB prompt) and pass it on to the program.

```
(gdb) handle SIGINT nostop pass
SIGINT is used by the debugger.
Are you sure you want to change it? (y or n) y
Signal        Stop      Print   Pass to program Description
SIGINT        No        Yes     Yes             Interrupt
```

We are now in the land of "slightly inadvisable," in that we can no longer use Ctrl+C to jump into our GDB prompt. You'll have to rely on preset breakpoints and other mechanisms.

If you want to get more advanced, you can use `catch` and `commands` to determine the source of the `SIGINT` (lifted from [Debugging a program that uses SIGINT with gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36993909/debugging-a-program-that-uses-sigint-with-gdb)):

```
catch signal SIGINT
commands
  if $_siginfo._sifields._kill.si_pid == 0
    print "Received SIGINT from tty"
  else
    printf "Received SIGINT from %d; continuing\n", $_siginfo._sifields._kill.si_pid
    signal SIGINT
  end
end
```